# How to get the nggallery album id from post using post id or preview id in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using nggallery plugin for displaying photo gallerys and gallery pictures.
Initially i am creating galleries and uploading pictures.
After i am creating post in that i am attaching gallery to post through editor.
After adding gallery i am getting this format data in post content

```
 <img class="ngg_displayed_gallery mceItem" src="http://photos.abc.com/nextgen-attach_to_post/preview/id--1233" alt="" data-mce-placeholder="1" />
```

Actually i am creating web services. I want Gallery id using Post. So that based on post id or preview id i need that post related ng gallery id. How to get Galley id using post id or preview id. Please help me.